# Fetch partial data in more frequent intervals, while keep fetching full data in less frequent intervals

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, database-design, architecture

I have a PHP script that currently fetches data and populates a DB table with the data fetched, after applying a serious of rules on it. Then, it makes some kind of calculation based on all data, and assign a value to each record in the data, based on calculation results.

A single run takes about 25 minutes, and I want to have fresh data as possible at any given time. 
So I guess can run this script only about every 30 minutes as cron job.

However, out the data that is being fetched, about 4/5 is does not change much within 30 minutes. 
I can target the script to fetch the 1/5 of the data that is expected to have more frequent changes between each query. This will take about 6-7 minutes to run.

The question is how may I create a script that will fetch that 1/5 of data every 10 minutes, and keep fetching the other 4/5 of data every 30 minutes, as eventually I need to display and make calculations on all the data together.

Should it be a single script, or two scripts? Should they be set as a cron job in given times, or not?

Should I use for example different tables, and make a view that takes both?

Also, what will happen on minute 30 when both script run together, I think both will finish slower than 30 and 10 minutes if both require the same MYSQL server to process (also the API server might raise more errors if I fetch it with 2 scripts at a time, not sure though).

What will be the correct way to this for performance and speed?

Comment: I'd investigate if existing script can speed up by optimizing queries or tuning server settings. 25 minutes is quite big time for recurrent job and if it is not updating millions of rows, I'd expect it should run faster.

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

Cron is not well suited for *continually* doing something.  It shines at periodically doing *some quick task*.

So, have a single program that continually loads all the data.  Or it has the smarts to reload part of the data a few times, then reload the rest of the data.

But, as soon as it finishes, it starts over.  Meanwhile, it would be wise to have a "keep-alive" program run by cron that does one quick task:  See if the downloader task is alive; if not, it restarts it.

If you are reloading an entire table, do it this way:

```
CREATE TABLE t_new LIKE t;
load the data by whatever means
RENAME TABLE t TO t_old, t_new TO t;
DROP TABLE t_old;
```

This way, `t` is always present and completely loaded.

If you are refreshing only part of the table, do something more like

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp ...;
load some data into `temp`
massage, if needed, that data
INSERT INTO t (...)
    SELECT ... FROM temp
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp;
```

If IODKU is not suitable, pick some other approach.  The main point is to have data readily available in some other table so you can rapidly copy it into the real table.  (Note: This approach locks the table for some period of time; the full replacement approach has virtually zero downtime.)

When possible, apply your 'rules' to the entire table's worth of data; do not process one row at a time.  (This could make a significant performance difference.)

Oh, I should elaborate on why I don't like cron for the main task.  Today, the task takes 25 minutes and runs every 30 minutes.  Tomorrow, something will have changed and it will take 35 minutes.  Now the next instance will be stepping on the first, perhaps making a mess.  Or maybe just slowing down.  If it is just slowing down, then the subsequent instance will probably be even slower because they are fighting for CPU, etc.  Eventually, the system will "hang" because "nothing" is getting done.  And you will instinctively reboot it.  My design completely avoids that.

Comment: Thanks. Can PHP do this efficiently? also, what about the calculation result that I want to insert, for example, make such calculation every 5 minutes and set a flag for all records that match some condition? should this be done also as some insert to the same table, or should the approach be totally different?

Comment: @user8411456 - Please give a breakdown of the 25 minutes of processing - "fetching"?  From some slow, remote, site?  Number crunching in PHP? And finally `INSERTing?  `UPDATEing`?  into the database?  What fraction of the 25 minutes for each phase?